# Ajuda com GROUP_CONCAT (MySql)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

Gostaria de usar um `grupo_concat` para `filename` e `answer` mas que não repetisse os valores de `filename` e `answer`

Segue sqlfiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f32d78/1/0

É uma questão que possui 2 imagens e 4 alternativas de A-D.

```
name        questionText        question    filename    answer
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           2.svg       Resposta A
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           3.svg       Resposta A
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           2.svg       Resposta B
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           3.svg       Resposta B
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           2.svg       Resposta C
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           3.svg       Resposta C
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           2.svg       Resposta D
PT-D08-H    Texto da questão    1           3.svg       Resposta D
```

> Este é o resultado que estou obtendo, ao usar o group_concat, como fazer para não repetir os valores de `filename` e `answer`

```
    name        questionText    question         group_concat(filename)                             group_concat(answer)
    PT-D08-H    Texto da...     1                2.svg,3.svg,2.svg,3.svg,2.svg,3.svg,2.svg,3.svg Resposta A,Resposta A,Resposta B,Resposta B,Resposta C,Resposta C,Resposta D,Resposta D
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi fazendo duas `views`, uma para `perguntas` e outra para `respostas`, depois basta selecionar as duas fazendo join, e usando o `group-concat` para `answer` e `filename`, funcionou perfeitamente, segue `fiddle` com a solução:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e86592/1/0